# GooglePay not showing in stripe payment option kotlin/jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, stripe-payments, android-jetpack-compose, google-pay

am trying to implement googlepay in my project I implemented stripe payment and it works just fine i just didn't get googlepay button in my interface

```
  val stripeLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
                contract = PaymentSheetContract(),
                onResult = {
                    viewModel.handlePaymentResult(it,mContext)
                })

            val paymentLauncher = rememberPaymentLauncher(
                "xxxxxxxxxx",
                "xxxxxxxxxx"
            ) {
                viewModel.handlePaymentResult(it)
            }
            val confirmPaymentParams by viewModel.confirmPaymentParams.collectAsState()
            confirmPaymentParams?.let { payment ->
                paymentLauncher.confirm(payment)
                viewModel.onPaymentLaunched()
            }

            val clientSecret by viewModel.clientSecret.collectAsState()
            clientSecret?.let {
                val args = PaymentSheetContract.Args.createPaymentIntentArgs(
                    it, PaymentSheet.Configuration(
                        googlePay = PaymentSheet.GooglePayConfiguration(
                            countryCode = "US",
                            environment = PaymentSheet.GooglePayConfiguration.Environment.Test,
                            currencyCode = "USD"
                        ), merchantDisplayName = "yyyy"
                    )
                )
                stripeLauncher.launch(args)
                viewModel.onPaymentLaunched()
```

as you can see in code I added for PaymentSheet Configuration googlepay option is there something am missing or i done wrong because i've been struggling in this for so long and no doc available to help

Comment: It needs to be run on a phone with the Google Wallet app installed and with a real Visa/Mastercard in the wallet, and it doesn't work in India or with the local Indian version of Google Pay, if you're located there. (https://support.stripe.com/questions/supported-payment-methods-currencies-and-businesses-for-stripe-accounts-in-india)

Comment: okay thank you for for the information so my code have no errors right ?